# Why does the Java HashMap implementation use transfer() instead of put() when resizing?

Tags: java, hashmap

In the Java 7 `HashMap` implementation, in the `resize` method, it calls [`transfer`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l486) which moves old elements to a new table. Why have they written a new method instead of calling `put` with all the old elements? The resize won't be triggered again due to [threshold](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l767). Calling `put` makes the code clearer.

```
/**
 * Transfers all entries from current table to newTable.
 */
void transfer(Entry[] newTable) {
    Entry[] src = table;
    int newCapacity = newTable.length;
    for (int j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
        Entry<K,V> e = src[j];
        if (e != null) {
            src[j] = null;
            do {
                Entry<K,V> next = e.next;
                int i = indexFor(e.hash, newCapacity);
                e.next = newTable[i];
                newTable[i] = e;
                e = next;
            } while (e != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this probably didn't deserve to be closed. Although technically this could be opinion-based, there is a significant difference between using `put` and `transfer` (as @JoachimSauer pointed out), which would seem to answer the question perfectly.

Comment: @HenryTwist I vote to reopen. It is not just opinion based. As JoachimSauer mentioned, the developer consider performance over code cleanness. I will consider GC time and `hashCode` as fact instead of opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One important difference is that `transfer` can make use of the fact that `Entry` objects already exist for each entry in two ways:

- it can reuse the `Entry` objects themselves to avoid having to allocate new ones (thus avoiding memory allocation and therefore reducing GC pressure).
- it can reuse the `hash` value stored in the `Entry` object thus avoiding having to call `Object.hashValue` on each key that's already in the map (which could theoretically be an expensive operation).

Basically: if `resize` was implemented simply in terms of `put` it would have to re-do a lot of work that can easily be avoided.

Later versions of the JDK have significantly more complex `HashMap` implementations, where even more complex `transfer` methods (or equivalent) are implemented.

It's also worth pointing out that even minor performance gains at the cost of less "simple" code are often worth it when done in the JDK itself: since `HashMap` is used in basically every Java program out there, having it be as performant as possible at the cost of slightly less readable cost is usually worthwhile trade-off. That same reasoning does **not** apply equally to most other software that us "mere mortals" write.